# covert kotlin's Unit to Java's String

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
  public String BeaconValue() {
    ProximityObserver proximityObserver =
            new ProximityObserverBuilder(mContext, ((MyApplication) mContext).cloudCredentials)
                    .onError(new Function1<Throwable, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.e("desks", "proximity observer error: " + throwable);
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .withBalancedPowerMode()
                    .build();
    ProximityZone zone = new ProximityZoneBuilder()
            .forTag("desks")
            .inNearRange()
            .onEnter(new Function1<ProximityZoneContext, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(ProximityZoneContext proximityZoneContext) {
                    NotificationsManager.this.beaconValue = proximityZoneContext.getAttachments().get("desk-owner");
                    return null;;
                }
            })
            .build();
    proximityObserver.startObserving(zone);

    return this.beaconValue;
}

// Getting the beacon attachment value string
public String getBeaconValue() {
    beaconValue = BeaconValue(beaconValue);
    return beaconValue;
}
```

so this is the code here, currently I have the Unit, but after some research, I found out that Unit is implicit so it does not need to return anything and it does not really return anything.
However, I want to return the beaconValue in this function, so I made this new function to get the implicit Unit from the beaconvalue function, it does not work. Wondering why.
(I have tried to change the Unit to String, but that is not the way it gives error. since on enter does not support String (Java))
Thank you.

updated.

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: if you sure that you all that  you need is get String from Unit then use unit.toString(). But it will not give you something interesting. Else try to share more code

Comment: just updated, now this is the whole function

Comment: You can't convert a Unit to a String, they're unrelated concepts.  There's also no Kotlin code here that _could_ return Unit.  It's unclear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

The method returns `Unit` because you have declared it as the return type on the `Function1` object. Change the types in the `Function1` declaration to`<ProximityZoneBuilder, String>` if the `onEnter` function allows for any type. If it specifically requires `Unit` then you must use `Unit`.

Comment: yes but that gives "on enter in Unit call back cannot be applied to String", I guess it does not allow for any type. so I am wondering if there is any workaround

Comment: Then you cannot return String. It doesn't look like you need to return a String value because you are already setting the variable anyway. Also you are creating new ProximityObserver and ProximityZone objects everytime you call getBeaconValue() which is probably not what you want. Try setting those in another methiod or the constructor. And there you can set the beaconValue which should then be returned when you call getBecaonValue().

Comment: public String getBeaconValue(ProximityZoneContext context){
        beaconValue = BeaconValue(beaconValue);
        return beaconValue;
    } this is a new function I made. and after i created this, i also changed the "beaconValue = proximityZoneContext.getAttachments().get("desk-owner");" to "NotificationsManager.this.beaconValue = proximityZoneContext.getAttachments().get("desk-owner");".